# Direct download google drive api

Tags: php, google-drive-realtime-api

Good Morning,

I'm having to develop a system for downloading a file from google drive direct, but the problem is that I did not know php so I was mounting part by part and so was creating form but, I arrived at a time that I can not solve the following problem, if anyone can help me ...

When I try to download the file, the following error appears:

```
An error occurred1: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_client", "error_description" : "The OAuth client was not found." }'
```

I only have one code page for this to work, and it's just this:

```
    <?php
require_once "google/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php";

require_once "google/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php";

require_once "google/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php";

require_once "google/vendor/autoload.php";

$DRIVE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
$CLIENT_ID = '';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = '';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = '';

function buildService() {//function for first build up service
global $DRIVE_SCOPE, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, $CLIENT_ID;

  $key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
  $auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
      $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      array($DRIVE_SCOPE),
      $key);
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setUseObjects(true);
  $client->setClientId($CLIENT_ID);
  $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
  return new Google_DriveService($client);
}
/**
 * Print a file's metadata.
 *
 * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param string $fileId ID of the file to print metadata for.
 */
function printFile($service, $fileId) {
  try {
    $file = $service->files->get($fileId);

    print "Title: " . $file->getTitle();
    print "Description: " . $file->getDescription();
    print "MIME type: " . $file->getMimeType();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}

/**
 * Download a file's content.
 *
 * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param File $file Drive File instance.
 * @return String The file's content if successful, null otherwise.
 */

function downloadFile($service, $file) {
$downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl();
if ($downloadUrl) {
$request = new Google_HttpRequest($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
$httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);
if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {

return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
} else {
// An error occurred.
return null;
}
} else {
// The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
return null;
}
}
try {

//https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9ez4Vc-n0DbWkV6VmtRZFJIbnhqU3d2QmNHTTZfWWJYZGM0
$file_id='1cKbjJzSJ4ZcedfFUEe2MwncsDYGRuScl';

$service=buildService();
//printFile($service,$file_id);
$file = $service->files->get($file_id);
header('Content-Type: '.$file->getMimeType());
print(downloadFile($service,$file));


  } catch (Exception $e) {
  print "An error occurred1: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

Can anyone help me in solving this error? It's been a while since I'm behind the answer but to this but I can not find

[image: Imagem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you using `ClientId` in `$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL` instead of right `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL` that must be something like `id-123@inductive-world-123456.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.
And than you must also set the ClientId:

```
$client->setClientId($clientId);
```

So the code will be like this:

```
$DRIVE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
$CLIENT_ID = 'fulasdaasd40dbsdfssdfam.gserviceaccount.com';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'id-123@inductive-world-123456.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'My-File.p12';

function buildService() 
{
    global $DRIVE_SCOPE, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, $CLIENT_ID;

    $key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH); 
    $auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
        $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        array($DRIVE_SCOPE),
        $key);
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setUseObjects(true);
    $client->setClientId($CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
    return new Google_DriveService($client);
}
```

Comment: Now the problem is another, it is seizing 'invalid_grant' ... Complete message error :  An error occurred1: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant", "error_description" : "Invalid JWT Signature." }'

Comment: @user3602803 did you fixed SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL and used right CLIENT_ID? Also is service email account matches the .p12 file?

Comment: Yes, I will update the topic and put an image so you can look at the settings

Comment: @user3602803 you mixed up SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL and CLIENT_ID in code) It must be `$CLIENT_ID = '234884101335-5lh61u0m8gh5jbnfurags39vc0neu17u.apps.googleusercontent.com';` and 
`$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'fullacess@db360-196715.iam.gserviceaccount.com';`

Comment: It's because I've tried both ways, changing continues with literally the same error =\

Comment: @user3602803 so are you sure that .p12 file is for that service account? Did you see that account here https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/ and key created here?

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, it really was the .p12 file that was wrong, I changed it and the error disappeared, but now you are saying that the file was not found. O. Would you know to answer me why? (I changed the id and tried with several files, I confirmed that the share was enabled and still nothing!) Error Message: An error occurred1: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1m8BTncxKhQCW9hRHa31t5S4v9t88o1aIYEpGkwKYzbU: (404) File not found: 1m8BTncxKhQCW9hRHa31t5S4v9t88o1aIYEpGkwKYzbU

Comment: @user3602803 did you shared it with SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL?

Comment: @user3602803 there is a documentation and examples for this library on it github. Also you can find a lot of examples of it in google search) The problem of your question was resolved. Try to do next steps yourself ;) It will be useful)

Comment: I shared now everything is going so well, I'm on the final stretch after so long ... Now just one last thing that's happening, the file is coming with the name of my php file and with the .php extension there it's coming all wrong ... When I manually change the ".php" to ".zip" from the to see that it is the right file .... By chance you know why this is happening?

Comment: Thank you very much anyway bro, you helped me too much, I was trying to solve this for years and could not do it at all, and alone I probably would not leave the place hahahah Thank you very much !!

Comment: You executing it in the browser? I think this way it downloads it as your script's name. Try to add after `header('Content-Type: '.$file->getMimeType());` new line - `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='my_file.zip');`

Comment: It worked! :) Thanks a lot for all the help. 
You helped me too much.